# In what ways has QGIS 2.x API changed making Plugin Builder Tutorial invalid?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt, qt4, pyqt

I am working on the [QGIS workshop Tutorial for QGIS Plugin Builder](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html) and notice that it is for QGIS 1.1. As this seems like a popular tutorial, in general, what are some areas of this tutorial that need to be changed since the QGIS 2.0 release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sound like that's caused by the API changes.

Did you double-check that you didn't miss any step when creating the GUI, e.g.

> change the name of the TextBrowser object to txtFeedback

The official documentation, which is kept up-to-date by the project team is http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had overlooked the ui attribute, and my object was not instantiating correctly. I updated this question to reflect the general premise that the QGIS Workshop 1.1 tutorial may need to reflect API changes.